# audiotrack: how to remove the background noise?

Tags: android, audiotrack, noise-reduction

I have two wav files with properties 44khz, stereo channels and 16bit. I am trying to mix both of them using audiotrack in android. I was able to mix them. But i get noise while playing. How to remove the noise.

The following is my code:

```
        int frequency = 44100;
        int channelConfiguration = AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_STEREO;
        int audioEncoding = AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT;

        int minbufferSize = AudioTrack.getMinBufferSize(frequency, channelConfiguration,audioEncoding);

        AudioTrack audioTrack = new AudioTrack(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, frequency,
                channelConfiguration, audioEncoding, minbufferSize,
                AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM);

        int bufferSize = 512;

        int count = 0;
        int count2 = 0;
        byte[] data = new byte[bufferSize];
        byte[] data2 = new byte[bufferSize];
        byte[] data3 = new byte[bufferSize];

        try{
            FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream("/sdcard/file1.wav");
            DataInputStream dataInputStream = new DataInputStream(fileInputStream);

            FileInputStream fileInputStream2 = new FileInputStream("/sdcard/file2.wav");
            DataInputStream dataInputStream2 = new DataInputStream(fileInputStream2);


            audioTrack.play();

            while((count = dataInputStream.read(data, 0, bufferSize)) > -1 && (count2 = dataInputStream2.read(data2, 0, bufferSize)) > -1){

                for (int i=0;i<data3.length;i++){

                    float samplef1 = (data[i] / 128.0f);
                    float samplef2 = (data2[i] / 128.0f);

                    float mixed = samplef1 + samplef2;

                    // reduce the volume a bit:
                    mixed *= 0.9;

                    // hard clipping
                    if (mixed > 1.0f) mixed = 1.0f;

                    if (mixed < -1.0f) mixed = -1.0f;

                    byte outputSample = (byte) (mixed * 128.0f);
                    data3[i] = outputSample;
                }
                audioTrack.write(data3, 0, count);
            }

            L.m("Thread completed");

            audioTrack.stop();
            audioTrack.release();
            dataInputStream.close();
            fileInputStream.close();
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            rawaudioisRunning = false;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            rawaudioisRunning = false;
        }
```

Comment: Digital signal processing with Fast Fourier Transform analysis. Not sure what to filter till we see a segment of your audio analyzed in the frequency domain.

Comment: do you have any example for mixing two streams with FFT

Comment: mix two streams?  You just sum both streams of data in the time domain. If you want to filter noise out, you need to identify what frequencies are involved.  And that requires Fast Fourier Transform analysis.  Here's a pretty awesome way to learn this stuff... [Free Coursera Class on Audio Signal Processing](https://www.coursera.org/learn/audio-signal-processing/)

Comment: In the code example above, you are directly adding (mixing) the sampled content from file1.wav and file2.wav with the line of code `float mixed = samplef1 + samplef2;`  I will say, I don't understand why you are dividing the sample by 128, and why you are doing the clipping, and then multiplying by 128.  My guess is the clipping is causing you audio quality troubles... Keep it simple.